# How to transfer a metric to the orthonormal coordinate?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensors, general-relativity

Suppose in Cartesian coordinate system a Minkowski metric for flat spacetime can be written as :
 $$ ds^2 = -[1 + 2ψ(t,x)]dt^2 + a^2(t) [1 - 2ψ(t,x)]dx^2 $$
This is a diagonal metric. How can I transform this metric to the orthonormal frame? For that case, what will be the components of this metric in the orthonormal frame?

Comment: Do you mean, how can you produce a psuedo-orthonormal frame for the metric?

Comment: Yes, I mean that exactly.

Comment: You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423648/how-to-find-orthonormal-frame-of-given-metric/2423803#2423803).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the metric is diagonal, we can do compute this quickly: (Assuming $1 \pm 2 \psi(t, x)$ are both positive, and suppressing the arguments of $a, \psi$) we can rewrite the metric as
$$ds^2 = -(\sqrt{1 + 2 \psi} \,dt)^2 + [a \sqrt{1 - 2 \psi} \,dx]^2, $$
so in terms of the $1$-forms $$\alpha = \sqrt{1 + 2 \psi} \,dt, \qquad \beta = a \sqrt{1 - 2 \psi} \,dx$$
the metric has the form
$$ds = - \alpha^2 + \beta^2 .$$
In particular, the basis dual to $(\alpha, \beta)$, namely,
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2 \psi}} \partial_t, \frac{1}{a \sqrt{1 - 2 \psi}} \partial_x\right),$$ is pseudo-orthonormal.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer with a clear explanation. I am extremely sorry for asking you again. Can you please give another explanation about what will be the components of the pseudo-orthonormal frame if the metric will be symmetric but not diagonal. For example, a symmetric metric for Minkowski flat spacetime is  $$ ds^2 = -a^2 (t)[ [1 + 2ψ(t,x,y,z)]dt^2 + 2B_i (t,x,y,z) dx^i dt - [1 - 2ψ(t,x,y,z)] δ_{ij} dx^i dx^j ]$$ @Travis

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest asking that as a separate question. It will make it easier for others who have the same question to find it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.